# Make synchronous Http/REST call in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I have been working on Windows Phone 7 application & was trying to make synchronous REST call by using HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() but the compiler was complaining that the GetResponse() is not available. I found the BeginGetResponse() and EndGetResponse() in HttpWebRequest. But as I read that these two methods are used for asynchronous calls.

Our design has been implemented to support synchronous request only, could anyone please let me know "Is there any way to make synchronous call in WP7"

Comment: No, you cannot make synchronous calls because they can block the UI. Silverlight does not include any synchronous I/O calls.

Comment: @Gabe: There is actually no harm in synchronous requests if you do them from a worker thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate synchronous requests by blocking on an `AutoResetEvent` until the asynchronous call returns. [See here for a reference implementation.](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/adding-synchronous-methods)

Comment: I use something very similar to this. Two things to note; 1. The `AutoResetEvent`s are not being cleaned up correctly - they should be moved into a `using () { }` block. 2. These methods **must** be called from a background thread. If they're called on the UI thread they will **deadlock**.