# WP7 synchronous web request

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I’m developing a Windows Phone 7.1 application, and trying to implement tombstoning.

Due to the legal reasons I can’t save my view model. I’m only saving encrypted session ID, which can be used to load a view model data from the remote server.

On resume, I need to verify the session ID, if it’s expired – I take user to the login page of my app, if it’s still OK, I reload view model data from the server.

The problem is the HttpWebRequest lacks blocking API. Moreover, while inside page.OnNavigatedTo method after de-tombstoning, the method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262218/126995) blocks forever.

I’ve worked around the problem by presenting my own splash screen.

However, I’d rather like to complete those RPC calls while the system-provided “Resuming…” splash screen is visible, i.e. before I return from page.OnNavigatedTo method.

Any ideas how can I complete HTTP requests synchronously while inside page.OnNavigatedTo after de-tombstoning?

Answer (score 0):

Update: another option is to use [Reactive Extensions](http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2011/03/30/Using-a-new-pattern-to-call-the-network-with-Reactive-Extensions.aspx).

If you're on VS2010 you can install the [AsyncCTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983) and when you do an extension method gets added that allows you to await the response.

```
static async Task<Stream> AsynchronousDownload(string url)
  {
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    return (response.GetResponseStream());
  }
```

then:

UPDATED:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            var myResponse = await AsynchronousDownload("http://stackoverflow.com");
        }
```

or

If you're using VS2012 you can install the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx) lib and do the same thing as if you were using the AsyncCTP, `await` the response.

or

You could implement something similar to [Coroutines](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IResult%20and%20Coroutines&referringTitle=Documentation) in Caliburn Micro.  For this you implement the IResult interface.

```
 public interface IResult
{
    void Execute(ActionExecutionContext context);
    event EventHandler<ResultCompletionEventArgs> Completed;
}
```

A possible implementation:

```
public class HttpWebRequestResult : IResult
    {
        public HttpWebRequest HttpWebRequest { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }

        public HttpWebRequestResult(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        }

        public void Execute (ActionExecutionContext context)
        {
            HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse (Callback, HttpWebRequest);
        }

        public void Callback (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                Result = reader.ReadToEnd();

            Completed (this, new ResultCompletionEventArgs ());
        }

        public event EventHandler<ResultCompletionEventArgs> Completed = delegate { };
    }
```

Then to call it:

```
var httpWebRequestResult = new HttpWebRequestResult("http://www.google.com");
            yield return httpWebRequestResult;
            var result = httpWebRequestResult.Result;
```

[This](https://github.com/bugsense/BugSense-Windows-Phone-library/tree/master/BugSense/Coroutines) might be an example of grabbing the Coroutines implementation from CM and using it separately.

Comment: Using VS 2010 and async CTP. Task.Wait() blocks forever. Task.RunSynchronously throws exception at once. AsyncHelpers.RunSync unavailable because SetSynchronizationContext requires full trust.

Comment: Task.Wait isn't the same as await someTask.  See the new async/await keywords.

Comment: Derek, I can't use await inside OnNavigatedTo virtual method because it's not async.

Comment: Derek, I tried that. It doesn't solve my problem. The function returns not when it completes, but on the first await. Because of that, system-provided splash screen saying "resuming..." disappears much earlier than I need to.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start out by saying that Microsoft really tries to push you to do async calls for good reasons, which is why I wanted to emphasize it.

Now if you really want to do it synchronous, I have an idea which I haven't been able to test myself. When using the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class, there are two important functions, which you've probably used as well: [BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [EndGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.endgetresponse%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

These two functions work closely together. `BeginGetResponse` starts a asynchronous webrequest, where when the request is finished the `EndGetResponse` gives you to ouput when it's done. This is the way MS tries to let you do it. The trick to doing this stuff synchronously is that the `beginGetResponse` returns a [IAsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This `IAsyncResult` interface contains a [WaitHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which can be used to synchronously wait until the request is done. After which you can just continue with the endGetRequest and go on with your bussiness. The same thing goes for the [BeginGetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [EndGetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7de1x8cb%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

But as I said before, I haven't tested this solution and it's purely theoretical. Let me know if it worked or not.

Good luck!

Comment: Based on my tests, BeginGetResponse never returns while in OnNavigatedTo context after de-tombstoning.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little further? I don't understand what you're trying to say. Are you saying that the BeginGetResponse method never returns the IAsyncResult or never returns at all? Are you using the AsyncCTP like Derek Beattie said?

Comment: Depends on the thread. If launched from the main thread, it returns IAsyncResult but the callback never called. If launched in a pool thread, it never returns result, instead it deadlocks, with the following methods in the stack: ClientHttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse - AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI - AsyncHelper.CheckUseLowLatencyNetworking - Dispatcher.FastInvoke - EventWaitHandle.WaitOne - PInvoke.PAL.Threading_Event_WaitMultiple

Comment: I'm currently not able to test it my self, but it seems my solution won't work than. If I find something that might work i'll let you know.