# OnNavigatedTo and async/await in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigation, windows-phone-8

The question is rather about best practices. I have a PhoneApplicationPage with OnNavigatedTo overriden, and I want to await some async call there. What will happen to navigation when some call is awaited? My assumption is that navigation will not complete until the awaited call returns. By extension, it will render the async nature of the call useless. Is it true?

Another thing is that OnNavigatedTo returns void, and I cannot change this to the Task. This, in turn, means that any exception inside my async method will crash the app completely. Of course it's possible to catch exceptions, but again I'm concerned about if it's a good approach.

To sum up: anyone uses async/await in OnNavigatedTo? What is your experience? How likely is that you'll recommend it you to your friend or colleague? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, my answer relates to WP7 + Async CTP, not WP8. However, I doubt this was changed in WP8.

> My assumption is that navigation will not complete until the awaited
>   call returns

Wrong assumption. Navigation will complete on the first await.

> any exception inside my async method will crash the app completely

Not necessarily. You can subscribe to `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event, and mark the exeption as observed by calling `UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs.SetObserved`. But I'd rather catch exceptions..

> How likely is that you'll recommend it you to your friend or colleague?

It works OK if you understand what you're doing. However because the navigation will complete long before your async method will finish, the approach brings very little value.

P.S. My question "[WP7 synchronous web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283607/wp7-synchronous-web-request)" on the related topic - no answer given :-(

Comment: What I'm going to do in OnNavigatedTo is to get View Model's values from cache and in the same time start updating them (here's comes async stuff), so it's fine if async will method complete much later. What I've also done is a check if the navigation completes even despite long await. Indeed it does, you're right. I guess I'll go this way.