# Azure mobile services information is not still updated (async)

Tags: c#, mobile, azure, service, windows-8.1

In my application I've a list page with a gridview and a secondary page for editing the item information.
Sometimes when I save the data in the second page via UpdateAsync, the control is returned to the list page but the item information is not still updated.

In the list page I'm reading items data from mobile services using OnNavigatedTo like this:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    await viewModel.RefreshDataAsync();
}
```

And in the edit details page I'm saving data using OnNavigationFrom like this:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    await viewModel.SaveDataAsync();
}
```

After debugging RefreshDataAsync it seems that sometimes I'm reading data from mobile services when UpdateAsync have not finished saving data yet.
Is this the best way to save and read data or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This question is already resolved here:
[OnNavigatedTo and async/await in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685590/onnavigatedto-and-async-await-in-windows-phone)

Basically, OnNavigatedFrom is fired and forgot. Which means, it will return as soon as your call to SaveDataAsync is made.